# Looking to substitute roman numbers

Tags: regular-expression

I have a huge text file with Roman numbers for the paragraphs and I want to substitute them:

```
text text ... text

I

text ...

II

and so on
```

My question is: what regular expression describes one Roman number per line?

In other hand this one `/^\vM{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$` seems to be ok, except that it includes all blank lines.
How refactor it in a way to exclude the empty lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a look-behind assertion to check the length of the matched string:

```
\v^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$.@<=
```

`.` means match any one character (i.e., zero characters will not work).

`@<=` means look behind and accept only if the preceding atom (i.e., `.`) matches text immediately before this position in text.

This assertion will fail if the line is empty.